# gitlab rest-api how to link job/pipeline to project schedules

Tags: gitlab-api

Most projects have many pipeline schedules, I can link jobs to pipelines and project but not to the pipeline schedule that initiated the job. I'm trying to create a simple status-wall with jobs in red/green and if you press it you rerun the schedule. Heavily inspired by: https://github.com/jan-molak/jenkins-build-monitor-plugin.

Below are pipeline schedules for a project:

```
    {
        "project_id": "1518",
        "schedules": [
            {
                "id": 411,
                "description": "qa-04 provision users for demo",
                "ref": "test1-20210318",
                "cron": "6 18 * * *",
                "cron_timezone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
                "next_run_at": "2021-06-22T16:10:00.000Z",
                "active": true,
                "created_at": "2020-10-28T08:06:49.012Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-21T16:10:10.107Z",
                "owner": {..}
            },
            {
                "id": 410,
                "description": "test12 Demo fido2 solution fullstack test",
                "ref": "master",
                "cron": "40 06 * * *",
                "cron_timezone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
                "next_run_at": "2021-06-23T04:45:00.000Z",
                "active": true,
                "created_at": "2020-10-27T14:32:07.156Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-22T04:45:29.164Z",
                "owner": {..}
            },
            {
                "id": 409,
                "description": "test1 Demo fido2 solution fullstack test",
                "ref": "master",
                "cron": "05 04 * * *",
                "cron_timezone": "Europe/Copenhagen",
                "next_run_at": "2021-06-23T02:10:00.000Z",
                "active": true,
                "created_at": "2020-10-27T13:36:09.062Z",
                "updated_at": "2021-06-22T02:10:34.070Z",
                "owner": {..}
            }
        ]
    }
```

And here is a job executed by pipeline, but not by which schedule_id:

```
        "project_id": "1518",
        "jobs": [
            {
                "id": 3549568,
                "status": "failed",
                "stage": "test",
                "name": "test12",
                "ref": "master",
                "tag": false,
                "coverage": null,
                "allow_failure": false,
                "created_at": "2021-06-22T04:45:31.465Z",
                "started_at": "2021-06-22T04:45:33.354Z",
                "finished_at": "2021-06-22T05:00:03.734Z",
                "duration": 870.37944,
                "queued_duration": 1.029369,
                "user": {..},
                "commit": {..},
                "pipeline": {
                    "id": 489545,
                    "project_id": 1518,
                    "sha": "673073d3987fea3bb30a9433e15612712795c2cb",
                    "ref": "master",
                    "status": "failed",
                    "created_at": "2021-06-22T04:45:31.360Z",
                    "updated_at": "2021-06-22T05:00:03.874Z",
                    "web_url": "<url>/demo/demo-fullstack-test/-/pipelines/489545"
                },
                "web_url": "..",
                "artifacts_file": {..},
                "artifacts": [..],
                "runner": {..},
                "artifacts_expire_at": "2021-06-29T05:00:02.126Z",
                "tag_list": [ ]
            },
```

I can try to match the scheduler description with the name in the job, or try to check the job started_at with what that can match the crontab. Is there any other gitlab api that show this mapping I may have overseen.

Comment: Hey, did you find the answer?

Comment: @MistyK, Sorry, I've added a cache that holds jobs sorted on name, the name matches the name used by the scheduler. the main problem is that it take so long to navigate backwards on large projects, and if its not in the cache it can take 10 minutes.

Comment: makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The API was enhanced in Gitlab 15.3 to support this:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipeline_schedules.html#get-all-pipelines-triggered-by-a-pipeline-schedule

Comment: This is an improvement, the best would be to add the scheduler_id to each job, currently it says scheduled and the name of the scheduler, then you have to look up the scheduler id via the matching name.